# Slope of a Regression

Tags: regression, conditional-expectation

[image]

Given this chart, how do you determine the slope of the regression Y on F?

Comment: As the same number of observations is given for each pair of values, it does not affect the calculation for the slope itself. To get just the slope, just supply the first two rows for F and E() to your nearest friendly regression routine.

Comment: @Nick You can do better, because there is enough evidence of heteroscedasticity here to exploit using the third row. Your solution has a fit of $(32.33, 39.33, 46.33)$ whereas (in light of the high variance in the third column) the better one fits the first two columns more closely, giving $(32.15, 39.59, 47.03)$.

Comment: @whuber Fair point that the third row is information too; indeed with that variability structure the assumption of linearity may itself be moot.

Comment: @whuber thank you for responding, but I'm not following.  Maybe I should've supplied this information originally.  E(Y|F=f) is the sample mean of Y conditional on F=f.  Var(Y|F=f) is the conditional variance.  Does that change it or am I just fundamentally misunderstanding something?

Comment: whuber is simply pointing out that variance should be accounted for when you run the regression, so include the inverse of the variance as weights for each of the three points and you get a better fit.

Comment: Just to be clear @whuber you're advocating inverse variance weighted regression?

Comment: @whuber Can you post how you arrived at those numbers?  I don't follow it clearly.

Comment: @AsymLabs In R, you can just use the command `lm(c(32,40,46) ~ c(1,2,3), weights=1/c(6,8,40))`. To get slope = 7.4359 and intercept = 24.7179.  That gives the fit whuber described.  It's a regression weighted according to the inverse of the variance.

Answer (score 1):

@AsymLabs In R, you can just use the command lm(c(32,40,46) ~ c(1,2,3), weights=1/c(6,8,40)). To get slope = 7.4359 and intercept = 24.7179. That gives the fit whuber described. It's a regression weighted according to the inverse of the variance.